# join android tables and own tables

Tags: android, sql, join, android-contentprovider, contacts

I have some tables:

In android:

```
Contacts (ContactsContract (android database)): ContactsId, DisplayName, Thumbnail Uri

Phone (android database): ContactsId, Number, Number_Type
```

In My App:

```
MyMessageTable (my app database): Number, myMessageId, etc
```

Now I need a row like below:

```
Number, Number_Type, DisplayName , Thumbnail Uri, myMessageId , etc
```

And I want use up row in cursor loader to shown in UI.
But the problem is I could not join my tables with android tables.

Solutions:

1. Query each table separate and handle it in upper level (problem : could not send multi cursor to cursor loader and use it in UI)
2. Join android table and phone table after that join the result with MyMessageTable (problem: Join two different tables in two different data base?)
3. Cache Contacts and Phone table in RAM and handle it in upper level and send just `MyMessageTable` cursor to UI. (problem : Ram usage and need time to cache android tables in ram)
4. Copy android tables to new tables in my app and join with `SQLiteQueryBuilder` and update my tables with `ContentObserver`.(problem : need time to copy and `ContentObserver` does not work when application is close.)

5.Use `CursorJoiner`.but I could not push more than one `cursor` to `UI`.

Do you have any better idea?

Comment: 6 what about a custom CursorWrapper ?

Comment: @pskink CursorWrapper just filter result.or there is some thing i do not know....

Comment: from the docs "The primary use for this class is to extend a cursor while overriding only a subset of its methods" so you can easly add some virtual columns by overriding couple of methods

Comment: @pskink i need a cursor loader for my UI.i could not use cursor to make a cursor builder

Comment: i know that you need a cursor loader, then create your custom content provider returning your cursor in query() method

Comment: @pskink i could not recognize..could you please explain more or a example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49348/discussion-between-mimad-and-pskink)

Answer (score 0):

create some cursor wrapper like this (its a poor man's implementation yet shows how to do it):

```
class CW extends CursorWrapper {
    public CW(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    // TODO you will probably need to override these methods:
    // public int getColumnCount()
    // public int getColumnIndex(String columnName)
    // public int getColumnIndexOrThrow(String columnName)
    // public String getColumnName(int columnIndex)
    // public String[] getColumnNames()

    @Override
    public String getString(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex < super.getColumnCount()) {
            return super.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        return "extra column for row #" + getPosition();
    }
}
```

and test it:

```
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] proj = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor c0 = cr.query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
    while (c0.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate [" + c0.getString(0) + "]");
    }
    c0.close();

    Cursor c1 = new CW(cr.query(uri, proj, null, null, null));
    while (c1.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate [" + c1.getString(0) + "] [" + c1.getString(1) + "]");
    }
    c1.close();
```